# Unable to solve Broken -Count error>0

Tags: apt, package-management

I've recently installed Ubuntu 16.04, dual boot on my old Macbook.
In the last few days I've gotten an error message.

```
BrokenCount >0
```

The result is I can't install or remove anything from the Software Center.

I also entered the command

```
gksu software-properties-gtk
```

This returned:

```
file is locked/var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried S  sudo-i. Then I entered my password. The result was:root@aldo tilde#exit.the brokencount sign still exists on the top bar.

Comment: the problem ha been  resolved. I just entered :  apt-get install -f.and the broken count  sign  disappeared as  if it was a magic  command. Thanks  a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The  problem has been resolved. I just  entered:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

And the broken count sign disappeared as if by magic.

Comment: This didn't work for me